# Sharepoint calendar - previous entry does not get deleted while dragging and dropping entry

Tags: sharepoint-calendar

I managed to connect Sharepoint calendar to Outlook calendar. Now Outlook calendar appears (left)  and SharePoint Calendar (right) 
When I drag and drop an event from outlook calendar to sharepoint calendar (left to right), the  calendar sync does happen on the Sharepoint site, however the previous entry appears as a copy below the entry which is entered now.. Any fix for this?